# How to avoid `case` when handling `Maybe`

Tags: haskell

I am writing interpreter in Haskell and I have map: name_of_function -> defintion of function.

```
Map String Defun
```

My interpreter monad:

```
type InterpreterMonad  = StateT (EnvFun, (Stack EnvEval)) (ErrorT String IO ) ()
```

And as you can see "last" monad is `ErroT`.

Now, when I would like handle calling functions:

```
   handleFCall :: Stmt -> InterpreterMonad
    handleFCall (VarName name) args =  get >>= \(envFun, contextStack) -> case (Map.lookup (VarName name) envFun) of 
        Nothing -> throwError "Err"
        (Just x) -> DoSthOther
```

And as you can see I have to use `case`. However I am using `>>=` so I would like to avoid `case of` here. But, `Map.lookup` return `Nothing` on fail and I would like to add my error message.

I have no experience in Haskell so I don't know how to deal with it . Morever, every criticism to my code is welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a case statement, although reformatted with do notation your function would look more like

```
handleFCall (VarName name) args = do
    (envFun, contextStack) <- get
    case Map.lookup (VarName name) envFun of
        Nothing -> throwError "Err"
        Just x -> doSthOther x
```

Which would be more familiar to other Haskell programmers.  However, if you really want to avoid using a case, just use the `maybe` function:

```
handleFCall (VarName name) args = do
    (envFun, contextStack) <- get
    maybe (throwError "Err") doSthOther $ Map.lookup (VarName name) envFun
```

Or with `>>=`

```
handleFCall (VarName name) args
    = get >>= 
        (\(envFun, contextStack) ->
            maybe (throwError "Err") doSthOther
                $ Map.lookup (VarName name) envFun
        )
```

But personally I find the case statement more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The [`errors` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) has the following operations in [`Control.Error.Util`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html) (and reexported from `Control.Error`):

```
-- You can turn `Maybe` into `Either` by supplying a constant to use
-- for the `Left` case.
note :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b

-- Ditto for `MaybeT` and `ExceptT`
noteT :: Monad m => a -> MaybeT m b -> ExceptT a m b

-- And there are useful shortcuts for other combinations
failWith :: Applicative m => e -> Maybe a -> ExceptT e m a
```

`failWith` in particular looks like it would fit quite nicely here, something like this expression would do the trick.

```
failWith "Err" (Map.lookup (VarName name) envFun)
```

Note that the `ErrorT` transformer that you're using in your example has been deprecated in favor of `ExceptT` (as the signatures above are using), so you'd have to change your code accordingly to use the `errors` package.  On the other hand these functions are simple enough that you can just bake your own if you so prefer.